# What rsync options to use for the below mentioned scenario?

Tags: unix, rsync, syslog, rsyslog

Greetings !!!

This is regarding a specific requirement about rsync that we are trying to achieve. We have tried to achieve this by using various rsync options. However, we are encountering different problems with different rsync options.

Background: • We have a process (running on AIX) logs from which are getting logged in A.log (present in logs directory). • A.log gets rotated to A.CURRENT_DATE_TIME.log once it reaches 100 MB and new A.log is created. • We are transferring these logs to a centralized server using rsync. We are using rsync on the complete logs directory. • INODE of the files on the source server and the destination server are different. • Once the logs are in the centralized server, the idea is to get these logs read/indexed by a centralized log process which will pick the input from this centralized server.

Problem: • Although, A.log (destination server) is given as input to the centralized log process, it considers the INODE of the file and not the actual filename. • So, when the A.log file gets rolled over, the new A.log has a new INODE which is not detected by the centralized process. This was happening when we were using -u –r –t options with rsync. So in this case, INODE of the file was changing with everytime rsync happened and also when the rollover happen. Hence, the process stops indexing as it looks for the old INODE which is not present.

• The idea is to use rsync with a combination of options that would not change the INODE of the file at the time of rsync but should change the INODE at the time of rollover when A.log rotates to A.CURRENT_DATE_TIME.log. So, in order to achieve this, we included the –inplace option and we are able to retain the INODE at the rsync and INODE changes at the time of file rotation. However, it gives us a different issue now where file name doesn’t change and always remains A.log. So once the process is done indexing the A.log, it halts.

It would be great if someone can suggest something that could help us in achieving the mentioned requirements.

Regards, Puneet Sinha Middleware Administrator

Comment: `INODE of the files on the source server and the destination server are different.`  Of course they are.  An inode is assigned when a file is created. In this case when rsync creates the new file on the destination server.   It's specific to that local filesystem.  It would be sheer coincidence if the inodes were ever the same between two systems.  An inode has to be unique for the entire filesystem.  The right way to fix this is to change the process to stop looking at inodes.  rsync has nothing to do with inodes other than it creates files and files have inodes.

Comment: You should look some other way of changing your logging process, this looks too complex and prone to error.

Comment: Is your log rotating done by logrotate.conf (logrotate.d)? If so can you please show us the contents of the conf file? If not...why? This is what logrotate is used for and you shouldn't need a custom script.

Comment: Thanks for replying Jeight. We are not using logrotate.conf for log rotation. Logs are being rotated by WebSphere Application Server process which is generating the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend relying on the inode.  It will change any time the file moves from the source to the destination machine.  It will also change if the files are restored from backups.  If the log processing system depends on the inode, if you ever restore from backups the system will not work as you expected.

My recommendation is to NOT copy A.log, but only copy A.CURRENT_DATE_TIME.log.  This will simplify the project.

I suspect that the log processing system on the destination server is looking at the inode to determine if the file it had previously seen as A.log is now A.CURRENT_DATE_TIME.log.  That's not going to be reliable.

The above solution has 1 problem: The time it takes for a line in the log file to be generated to when it is processed by the centralized log process will increase. For example, if it takes 3 days for A.log to grow to 100 MB, then nothing from that file will enter the centralized log process for up to 3 days.  If the logs can't be delayed by more than 2 hours, then I would rotate the logs every 1 hour. That way you know you are within the 2 hour objective.